# too many arguments in foreign function call

Tags: r, rcpp

I am creating a package using rcpp.

I created a function which has 70 arguments. 9 of them are function calls.

```
NumericVector theFunc(const float A, ..
                      NumericVector B,...
                      ...
                      SEXP C_func_call)
```

When I try to call it (through R), it give me the message:

> `Error in .Call(_packagename_theFunc, A, ..:too many arguments in
>   foreign function call)`

Is there a limit in the number of arguments?
Is there a way to increase it?

Comment: MAX_ARGS in R 3.5 is 65, it is a complex problem because the limit is part of the source code of R, maybe you can reduce 5 arguments by passing some parameters as a vector.

Comment: I do not know offhand, but I find it very likely that either R or Rcpp cannot handle 70(!) arguments correctly. Are you absolutely sure there is no other way to define the interface? Could you just collect some of the arguments in a List (or S3 object)?

Comment: Thanks you both for the information.Unfortunately, I can't collect some of the arguments to a list.May be I need to totally redesign the problem.Thanks

Comment: This is (qualitatively) the same question as similar ones on the limits of elements in the `data.frame` constructor:  these things are macro-expanded code (for C++98) and _do_ have an upper limit -- so just _nest_ within `Rcpp::List`, if needed multiple times.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel:Ok, thanks.But, in order to create the list, don't I have to have the arguments of the function already?

Comment: You stick them 10 of them each into a list, transfer the resulting 7 lists to the functions and _inside_ the function unpack these into the 70 arguments you want to use.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel:Hmm!Nice!Thanks!Do you have any post on how to do that?(as a guide).I will try it and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, look for many related examples using `Rcpp::List` on this site, on the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) and in the [RcppExamples](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppExamples) package.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel:Ok, thank you!